# Explaining GitHub to a TFS user

Tags: github, workitem

I have started to use Cloud9 IDE recently and have to say I really like it as an individual. I use VS 2010 at work and TFS 2010 too. This made me think about the TFS equivalent for Cloud9. GitHub is something I have always been aware of but never really used.

I have done my research and read docs etc, what I really need some clarification in though is the whole Work Item system. I know GitHub has an Issue tracking but does it have a Work Item system similar to TFS. With the main features such as assigning work items to developers?

A little explanation to just clarify would be fantastic. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking for a way to have [Issues](https://github.com/features/projects/issues) show up like WorkItems in your task list in visual studio, I don't think there is a solution for this to date.

You can however assign developers to issues within GitHub:

1. Create or Edit an Issue
2. Click the `gear` next to "No one is assigned".
    [image: Assign Developer to an Issue]
3. Select a member from your `organization` to assign the issue to them.

Comment: This seems like a viable alternative. Thanks very much for your answer!